# Add call id to existing twilio numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

Our application will make out calls to customers using different `Twilio` numbers. Here is our sample code:

```
r.Dial customer_number, 
:method => 'POST', 
:timeout => '30'
```

We want to add a caller id/number to all these numbers so customers could always see one number if we call them. Is such option available on `Twilio`? We purchased a verified phone number which could be used as caller number.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

If I am understanding correctly, it seems like this could be a good case for one of our Copilot features, [Sticky Sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot#sticky-sender) where Twilio will maintain a mapping of the To and From numbers.

Otherwise, the [OutgoingCallerId instance resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids) represents a single verified number that may be used as a caller ID when making outgoing calls via the REST API and within the TwiML `<Dial>` verb. And there are some examples in Ruby there.

Let me know if this helps!

Edit: I stand corrected that the Sticky Sender feature only works with messaging services and not calling.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you have a verified number that you want to use as the caller ID then you just need to add one more attribute to your TwiML. The [`callerId` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id) lets you specify the caller ID that will appear to the called party when Twilio calls.

You can update your TwiML to:

```
r.Dial customer_number, 
  :method => 'POST', 
  :timeout => '30',
  :calledId => "YOUR_VERIFIED_NUMBER"
```

And your caller ID will be used for all your calls.

Comment: r.Dial :callerId => "YOUR_VERIFIED_NUMBER", :method => 'POST', :timeout => '30' do
          r.Number customer_number
  end

Comment: @phinash yes. it works. The only thing i'm not sure is that if the caller id could be used by multiple Dial from different numbers at same time.

Comment: Good stuff! Could you mark the answer as correct so that other people can see that this worked too? Thanks!